# How to display a VRML model with .NET?

Tags: .net, 3d, visualization, vrml

I have a request to display VRML models within a .NET application. Does someone know an easy way, maybe with standard .NET components, to achieve this? What are the issues I maybe have to face when representing VRML within an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself a VRML ActveX control an [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx) that into your .NET app, you should be able to find one at [www.web3d.org](http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/X3dResources.html)

Comment: er..um... have you SEEN a VRML ActveX control around recently?  Try Googling for one.  It's a rather barren field.  That's why I recommended moving to SVG.

Comment: VRML is interactive 3D, i just don't see how you are going to get to SVG. I can definitely find more VRML/X3D plugins than VRML to SVG converter.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion James but for my needs Haralds advise will be more satisfying. The reason is that you have not only to see the 3D objects but also to turning them around and zooming in and out.

Answer (score 2):

The VRML standard has evolved into X3D (which still supports the old syntax, but pushes an XML-based syntax now.  For anyone viewing this thread, it would be better to search for X3D and .Net rather than VRML and .Net.  Also, for the web, checkout [X3DOM](http://www.x3dom.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is that I hadn't seen anything/anyone using VRML in at least five years.  I think you may be better off just finding a VRML->SVG converter.  Displaying SVG in a browser is rather well-defined these days.

Comment: That is a bad idea. You will definitely lose some information with the conversion. Using XML-representation of VRML as X3D and X3DOM as parser might help.